# JavaScript: colliding divs issue

Tags: javascript

I have this colliding function which was originally written for two divs. I want to add more divs so I can create a game with several cars in a road (the objective is for the user to cross it without colliding). The issue is that I don't understand why only one div triggers the method and not both. I don't know if the problem is in the if statement.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var keycode = e.keyCode;
    var frog = $(".frog");
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keycode === 37) frog.css("left", (frog.position().left - 4) + "px");
    if (keycode === 38) frog.css("top", (frog.position().top - 4) + "px");
    if (keycode === 39) frog.css("left", (frog.position().left + 4) + "px");
    if (keycode === 40) frog.css("top", (frog.position().top + 4) + "px");
  });
});

   function collision($car, $secondCar, $frog) {

      var x1 = $car.offset().left;
      var y1 = $car.offset().top;
      var h1 = $car.outerHeight();
      var w1 = $car.outerWidth();

      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;

    //SECOND CAR

      var x3 = $secondCar.offset().left;
      var y3 = $secondCar.offset().top;
      var h3 = $secondCar.outerHeight();
      var w3 = $secondCar.outerWidth();

      var b3 = y3 + h3;
      var r3 = x3 + w3; 

      var x2 = $frog.offset().left;
      var y2 = $frog.offset().top;
      var h2 = $frog.outerHeight();
      var w2 = $frog.outerWidth();
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;



      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2 || 
b3 < y2 || y3 > b2 || r3 < x2 || x3 > r2 )  { 

          return false;

        }else {

            $frog.fadeOut();
        }

    }

window.setInterval(function() {
  (collision($('#car'), $('#secondCar'), $('#frog')));
}, 0);
```

EDIT:

If I have something like:

```
if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2 )  { 
          return false;
        }else {
            $frog.fadeOut();
        }
```

it works for the first car. But having the parameters of both cars nothing happens...

Or even if write like this, it works, but it's repeated code...

```
   function collision($car, $frog) {

      var x1 = $car.offset().left;
      var y1 = $car.offset().top;
      var h1 = $car.outerHeight();
      var w1 = $car.outerWidth();

      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;

      var x2 = $frog.offset().left;
      var y2 = $frog.offset().top;
      var h2 = $frog.outerHeight();
      var w2 = $frog.outerWidth();
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2  )  { 

          return true;

        }else {

            $frog.fadeOut();
        }

    }

function secondCollision($secondCar, $frog){
     var x3 = $secondCar.offset().left;
      var y3 = $secondCar.offset().top;
      var h3 = $secondCar.outerHeight();
      var w3 = $secondCar.outerWidth();

      var b3 = y3 + h3;
      var r3 = x3 + w3; 

      var x2 = $frog.offset().left;
      var y2 = $frog.offset().top;
      var h2 = $frog.outerHeight();
      var w2 = $frog.outerWidth();
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

    if ( b3 < y2 || y3 > b2 || r3 < x2 || x3 > r2 )  { 

          return true;

        }else {

            $frog.fadeOut();
        }

}


window.setInterval(function() {
  (collision($('#car'), $('#frog')));

}, 0);
window.setInterval(function() {
  (secondCollision($('#secondCar'), $('#frog')));

}, 0);
```

The Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/icenine/w3advz9u/

Comment: anyone has ideas might help?

Comment: are you able to provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I dont know why but the div(frog) in this fiddle doesnt respond to the keyboard...

Comment: it's the red box in the bottom

Comment: thanks, its just jquery needed to be loaded. got it

Comment: Look into object constructors and object oriented programming. It will help tremendously. When I was starting my coding journey, I completed the JS tutorial on Khan Academy. They do a pretty good job of teaching object-oriented approaches. https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming/objects/p/intro-to-objects

Comment: well, i thought in that aproach, but since I got this algorithm working I just tried to add a div, according to its logic, but something i'm not cathing up and it doesnt make sense...It shoul work like this

Comment: A while back I wrote a simple JS maze game with coins you can collect and a finish line to cross utilizing a [similar collision detection function](https://github.com/Daniel-Hug/maze/blob/gh-pages/js/app.js#L102) that you may be interested in: [src](https://github.com/Daniel-Hug/maze), [demo](http://daniel-hug.github.io/maze/). :)

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll get a look into it

Comment: Well, @Web_Designer, you have a great code and a cool game, and the colision logic it's similar, but I still dont get why shifting from one car to another the script works - in this code. Object oriented would take a diferent mind-set to acomplish it. Do you think it's possible getting the desired result with this script?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple, actually. Just need to call the collision function each time I add a new div, and pass it's ID as an argument. The whole script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var keycode = e.keyCode;
    var frog = $(".frog");
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keycode === 37) frog.css("left", (frog.position().left - 4) + "px");
    if (keycode === 38) frog.css("top", (frog.position().top - 4) + "px");
    if (keycode === 39) frog.css("left", (frog.position().left + 4) + "px");
    if (keycode === 40) frog.css("top", (frog.position().top + 4) + "px");
  });
});

   function collision($car, $frog) {

      var x1 = $car.offset().left;
      var y1 = $car.offset().top;
      var h1 = $car.outerHeight();
      var w1 = $car.outerWidth();

      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1; 

      var x2 = $frog.offset().left;
      var y2 = $frog.offset().top;
      var h2 = $frog.outerHeight();
      var w2 = $frog.outerWidth();
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;



      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2 )  { 

          return false;

        }else {

            $frog.fadeOut();
        }

    }

window.setInterval(function() {
  (collision($('#car'), $('#frog')));
}, 0);
window.setInterval(function() {  //-> the second call, now for second car
  (collision($('#secondCar'), $('#frog')));
}, 0);
```